# List Comprehension with Assignment Operation

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

My code has no error. But I am a little curious to know. Is there any way to write my code using list comprehension? I want to remove the outer loop(`for i in range(labels)`) and write it with list comprehension. Actually, I am facing problem regarding how can I make an assignment(`current_class_p = p[y == i]`) between inner and outer loops.

For example, `y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1])`, `p =np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])`, and confusion matrix for this [[1, 1],[1, 2]].

```
def confusion_matrix_version2(y, p):
  labels = len(np.unique(y)) 
  result = np.zeros((labels, labels), dtype=int)

  for i in range(labels):
    current_class_p = p[y == i]
    result[i] = [len(current_class_p[current_class_p == j]) for j in range(labels)]
  return result
```

Comment: please make this a working script. Create simple values for y and p and have your example call the function with these. This appears to be numpy related and numpy arrays are quite different than python lists. By making this a running script, we know the types of variables and can write answers that demonstrate the solution.

Comment: So you want to make a confusion matrix, with what I'm assuming is `y = true values` and `p = predicted_values`, right? Does it have to be list comprehension, or are you open to having an array?

Comment: @MD.ABUSAYED SAYED, My response gives your desired output for your inputs. If this works out for you, please mark it as the accepted answer. If not, please let me know if there's anything else that I can do

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sklearn`'s [confusion_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) to generate your desired output :

```py
>>> from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
>>> y_true = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
>>> y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2]
>>> cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2]])
```

where rows correspond to predicted values and columns correspond to actual values. If you want this as a nested list, you can use `cm.tolist()`

```py
>>> cm.tolist()
[[2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2]]
```

EDIT: Updated the list output from a list comprehension to the array's `tolist` function as per juanpa.arrivillaga's suggestion.

Comment: You should use `cm.tolist()` instead

Comment: You're right. I was under the impression that `tolist` was called when `list(array)` was called, but it just makes everything a nested list. Thanks for the suggestion! It's much cleaner now